# Wordpress pagination on homepage not working

Tags: wordpress, pagination

pls i need your help,

the pagination on my homepage does not work...whenevr i click on the  2 button to go to second page, i get a 404 error page.
here is the pagination code;

```
if ( !function_exists( 'pagination' ) ) {

function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)

{

 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;



 global $paged;

 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;



 if($pages == '')

 {

     global $wp_query;

     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

     if(!$pages)

     {

         $pages = 1;

     }

 }



 if(1 != $pages)

 {

     echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";

     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";

     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";



     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)

     {

         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))

         {

             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";

         }

     }



     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";

     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";

     echo "</div>\n";

 }
```

}

}

Comment: You can try to set query_vars['posts_per_page'] with the pre_get_posts action

Comment: pls how do i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in functions.php and try., Replace the post type and posts_per_page as you need..

```
function alter_query_vars($query)
{

    switch($query->query_vars['post_type'])
    {

        case 'post':
                //if($query->is_category()) Use this if you want to pagination on category page
                    $query->query_vars['posts_per_page']    =   6;

            break;

        default: 

            break;
    }

    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'alter_query_vars');
```